# Select using UNION ALL doubt

Tags: mysql, select, union

I'm doing a select using UNION ALL for a search page, so I  need to know from which table the result come from, for me do a link to the correct page.
It's possible?

Ex:

```
(SELECT id, title AS tit FROM video WHERE `title` LIKE '%test%')
UNION ALL
(SELECT id, title AS tit FROM testimonials WHERE `title` LIKE '%test%' AND _type = 'news')
UNION ALL
(SELECT id, title AS tit FROM image_gallery  WHERE `title` LIKE '%test%' AND id_gallery = '1')
```

Cheers Mango

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about adding the table name to the SELECT statements?

```
(SELECT id, title AS tit, 'video' as tname FROM video WHERE `title` LIKE '%test%')
UNION ALL
(SELECT id, title AS tit, 'testimonials' as tname FROM testimonials WHERE `title` LIKE '%test%' AND _type = 'news')
UNION ALL
(SELECT id, title AS tit, 'image_gallery' as tname FROM image_gallery  WHERE `title` LIKE '%test%' AND id_gallery = '1')
```

Comment: Thanks Rick, I dindnt know that is possible!

Answer (score 4):

Just add the table name to every subquery:

```
(SELECT 'video' as tablename, id, title AS tit 
 FROM video 
 WHERE `title` LIKE '%test%')
 UNION ALL
(SELECT 'testimonials' as tablename, id, title AS tit 
 FROM testimonials 
 WHERE `title` LIKE '%test%' AND _type = 'news')
 UNION ALL
(SELECT 'image_gallery' as tablename, id, title AS tit 
 FROM image_gallery
 WHERE `title` LIKE '%test%' AND id_gallery = '1')
```